# TypeScript type checking on type rather than instance (part 2)

Tags: typescript

Part one asks the question - "Is it possible for TypeScript to ensure that a parameter is of a given type or its derivatives, rather than an instance of a type or its derivatives?"

[TypeScript type checking on type rather than instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937550/typescript-type-checking-on-type-rather-than-instance)

The solution in part one is to use the `typeof` keyword

**Example**

```
function giveMeAType(type: typeof Foo): void {
}
```

or with generics

```
function giveMeAType<T extends typeof Foo>(type: T): void {
}
```

Expanding on this solution, I have a new problem when constructors are introduced to derived types

```
class Mangler<T> {
    protected constructor(
        public readonly item: T) {
    }

    public static getManglers(mangler: typeof Mangler): typeof Mangler[] {
        var whatever = [];
        return whatever;
    }
}

class StringMangler extends Mangler<string> {
    // No constructor override here...
}

class NumberMangler extends Mangler<number> {
    // But in this case, I need one...
    private constructor(
        public readonly item: number) {
        super(item);
    }
}

// This one works while StringMangler does not override the constructor.
Mangler.getManglers(StringMangler);

// But when I override the constructor, it doesn't work.
Mangler.getManglers(NumberMangler);
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Mangler%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20item%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getManglers(mangler%3A%20typeof%20Mangler)%3A%20typeof%20Mangler%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20whatever%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20whatever%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20StringMangler%20extends%20Mangler%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20NumberMangler%20extends%20Mangler%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20item%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(item)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20one%20works%20while%20StringMangler%20does%20not%20override%20the%20constructor.%0D%0AMangler.getManglers(StringMangler)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20when%20I%20override%20the%20constructor%2C%20it%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0AMangler.getManglers(NumberMangler)%3B)

How then do me maintain Type checking with constructor overrides?

P.S. I want the derived types to have the ability to have private or protected constructors!

**Update 1**

To elaborate on Nitzan Tomer's answer, I can make the constructor `protected`, and the error goes away, but I can't make the constructor polymophic...

```
class NumberMangler extends Mangler<number> {
    // This polymorphic constructor doesn't work.
    public constructor(
        public readonly item: number,
        public readonly name: string) {
        super(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to help with the "polymorphic constructor" problem, it will be best if you elaborate on how you plan to use this `Mangler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `NumberMangler.constructor` protected then the error goes away:

```
class NumberMangler extends Mangler<number> {
    protected constructor(
        public readonly item: number) {
        super(item);
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

This should work:

```
class NumberMangler extends Mangler<number> {
    protected constructor(item: number);
    protected constructor(item: number, name: string);
    protected constructor(
        public readonly item: number,
        public readonly name?: string) {
        super(item);
    }
}
```

You don't really need the non-implementation signatures, but I think it makes it more readable.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan...with a bit of playing I worked that out, but apologies, I neglected to point out in my question that overridden constructors can't be polymorphic. See my update.